# Parsing response in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

```
{
   "response":{
      "code":200,
      "message":"OK",
      "data":[
         {
            "user":{
               "id":"564564",
               "firstName":"XYZ",
               "lastName":"J.",
               "photo":"https:\/\/img-s.example.com\/userpix_thumbs\/48935_12545435354.png",
               "gender":"male",
               "homeCity":"Algonquin, IL",
               "contact":{

               }
            },
            "lastCheckin":34634543532
         },
         {
            "user":{
               "id":"3254353",
               "firstName":"PQR",
               "lastName":"Black",
               "photo":"https:\/\/img-s.example.com\/userpix_thumbs\/TJZE1FSTWBE5JA11.jpg",
               "gender":"male",
               "homeCity":"Chicago, IL",
               "relationship":"friend",
               "contact":{

               }
            },
            "lastCheckin":3534523422345
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Above is the response in `JSON` . I am Not able to parse the “user” content from above response. It always returns `0`  instead of the `firstName` and `lastName` fields. Please Help. Below is my code.

```
FSQAPIRec_CheckIn_Results g1 = new FSQAPIRec_CheckIn_Results();

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();

g1 = JSONHelper.Deserialise<FSQAPIRec_CheckIn_Results>(json);

if (g1.response.message == "OK")
{

    List<FSQCheckIn_Data> obj = g1.response.data;

    for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count(); i++)
        {
            List<FSQCheckIn_UserData> obj1 = obj[i].user;
            for (int j = 0; j < obj1.Count(); j++)
                lbl_Resent_Chechin.Text += (j + 1) + ") " + obj1[j].firstName + " " + obj1[j].lastName + "<br/><br/>";
        }
}


public class JSONHelper
{
    public static T Deserialise<T>(string json)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var serialiser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serialiser.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }

    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new      DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }



[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class FSQAPIRec_CheckIn_Results
{
    [DataMember]
    public RecCheckIn_Response response { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class RecCheckIn_Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public string code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<FSQCheckIn_Data> data { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class FSQCheckIn_Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<FSQCheckIn_UserData> user { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class FSQCheckIn_UserData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string photo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It may well not be relevant, but it's not great that you're using three different encodings here - in particular, UTF-8 (the default when constructing a StreamReader), Encoding.Unicode (in Deserialize) and Encoding.Default (in Serialize).

Comment: What did you already tried? Did you run in in the debugger?

Comment: Is it returning 0, or 0 elements.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I viewed this in debugging mode also. The obj object is returning me 2 objects but the count of user which is obj1 is returning count of 0.

Comment: @moguzalp, I just pasted that into one of the many JSON formatter/validator online tools and copied the result back. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1):

The `user` item is not a list, it's a single object.

```
...
if (g1.response.message == "OK") {
  List<FSQCheckIn_Data> obj = g1.response.data;
  for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count(); i++) {
    FSQCheckIn_UserData obj1 = obj[i].user;
    lbl_Resent_Chechin.Text += "1) " + obj1.firstName + " " + obj1.lastName + "<br/><br/>";
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Yes sir, I have changed it to List<FSQCheckIn_UserData> obj1 but still its giving me the count of 0.

Comment: @Rupesh What Guffa is pointing out is that each FSQCheckIn_Data has a single user, you need to change it to public FSQCheckIn_UserData user and it will work. Or change the json to return and array of user.

Comment: I was making an mistake of declaring user as public List of FSQCheckIn_UserData instead of public FSQCheckIn_UserData user.

And used the following to access the fields firstName and lastName,

    FSQCheckIn_UserData obj1 = obj[i].user;

    lbl_Resent_Chechin.Text += (i + 1) + ") " + obj1.firstName + " " + obj1.lastName + "<br/><br/>";


Thanks.